# I can't extract data from JSON result with PHP

Tags: json

This is the result from JSON query

```
{
  "ACSExecution_HasError": false,
  "ACSExecutionErrorMessage": "",
  "ACSOutputResponce": {
    "ACSValueOutput": [
      {
        "ACSObjectOutput": [
          {
            "GeoID": 1329068,
            "Resolved_Street": "kolopetinitsas",
            "Resolved_Street_Num": "48",
            "Resolved_Zip": "56432",
            "Resolved_Area": "tsalonika",
            "Resolved_Long": 32.9179268,
            "Resolved_Lat": 30.6484871,
            "Resolved_GeoDataType": 1,
            "Resolved_GeoDataID": 1329068,
            "Resolved_Station_ID": "ΘΟ",
            "Resolved_Branch_ID": 1,
            "Resolved_As_Inaccesible_Area_With_Cost": 0,
            "Resolved_As_Inaccesible_Area_WithOut_Cost": 0,
            "Resolved_Confidence": 87,
            "Resolved_GeoRegionType": 2,
            "Resolved_Providence": "N.Thessalonikis",
            "Resolved_Correction": "000",
            "Resolved_Station_Descr": "Monasthriou (2310-567462)",
            "AddressID": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ACSTableOutput": {}
  }
}
```

I want to extract the value Resolved_Station_ID
I tried this

```
$json = json_decode($response1,true);// decode the JSON feed 
echo "STATION ID=".$json->ACSValueOutput[0]->ACSObjectOutput[0]->Resolved_Station_ID;
```

but it's not working i get these errors

Notice: Trying to get property 'ACSValueOutput' of non-object in /home/deorum/public_html/pveshop.gr/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 116

Notice: Trying to get property 'ACSObjectOutput' of non-object in /home/deorum/public_html/pveshop.gr/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 116

Notice: Trying to get property 'Resolved_Station_ID' of non-object in /home/deorum/public_html/pveshop.gr/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 116

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
$json["ACSOutputResponce"]["ACSValueOutput"][0]["ACSObjectOutput"][0]["Resolved_Station_ID"]
```

You cant use `->` with an array, only with object. What you have is an associative array because of the `true` param in `json_decode()`. If you change to `json_decode(..., false)`, then you could get it this way:

```
$json->ACSOutputResponce->ACSValueOutput[0]->ACSObjectOutput[0]->Resolved_Station_ID
```